# Using Javascript to sort table with multiple digit entries

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a sortable table to my site but I'm having issues sorting columns with varying digit entries. It works fine when all numbers are the same number of digits in length.

However, when I change the number of digits, the sort function seems to break and sorts them out of order.

The code below is a simple example of this. The table I am working with is much larger and more interesting than people, their jobs and age.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Sorting Tables w/ JavaScript</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table-sortable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Occupation</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Dom</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Web Developer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Rebecca</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>Teacher</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>Civil Engineer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Andre</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>Dentist</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="./src/tablesort.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function sortTableByColumn(table, column, asc = true) {
    const dirModifier = asc ? 1 : -1;
    const tBody = table.tBodies[0];
    const rows = Array.from(tBody.querySelectorAll("tr"));

    // Sort each row
    const sortedRows = rows.sort((a, b) => {
        const aColText = a.querySelector(`td:nth-child(${ column + 1 })`).textContent.trim();
        const bColText = b.querySelector(`td:nth-child(${ column + 1 })`).textContent.trim();

        return aColText > bColText ? (1 * dirModifier) : (-1 * dirModifier);
    });

    // Remove all existing TRs from the table
    while (tBody.firstChild) {
        tBody.removeChild(tBody.firstChild);
    }

    // Re-add the newly sorted rows
    tBody.append(...sortedRows);

    // Remember how the column is currently sorted
    table.querySelectorAll("th").forEach(th => th.classList.remove("th-sort-asc", "th-sort-desc"));
    table.querySelector(`th:nth-child(${ column + 1})`).classList.toggle("th-sort-asc", asc);
    table.querySelector(`th:nth-child(${ column + 1})`).classList.toggle("th-sort-desc", !asc);
}

document.querySelectorAll(".table-sortable th").forEach(headerCell => {
    headerCell.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const tableElement = headerCell.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
        const headerIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(headerCell.parentElement.children, headerCell);
        const currentIsAscending = headerCell.classList.contains("th-sort-asc");

        sortTableByColumn(tableElement, headerIndex, !currentIsAscending);
    });
});
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated!! Thank you all so much for your help on this!

Comment: To sort by numeric value:
`return parseFloat(aColText) > parseFloat(bColText) ? (1 * dirModifier) : (-1 * dirModifier);`
Otherwise, sort will be by string value ("2" is bigger than "10").

Comment: @iAmOren that worked! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad to help!
I'll make it into an answer: could you select it?
It helps the ranking here.
Thank you!

Comment: I just selected it. I just noticed that my table now sorts columns with text out of order if they only contain alphabetical data. I would like those rows to still sort alphabetically. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Thank you!
Well, you need to flag somehow the columns: text or number.
You could use class in the header tags and check against that.
I don't know yet how to use the --data attribute.
I see you send `headerIndex` to the sort function - perhaps a local/global array with corresponding text/number?
`if(type[headerIndex]=="number") return parseFloat(aColText) > parseFloat(bColText) ? (1 * dirModifier) : (-1 * dirModifier);
else return aColText > bColText ? (1 * dirModifier) : (-1 * dirModifier);` or something like this.

Comment: I've been messing with your suggestion all day with no luck. I'm struggling to find the correct way to target a column of cells to determine if the value is numerical or alphabetical.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To sort by numeric value:

```
return parseFloat(aColText) > parseFloat(bColText) ? (1 * dirModifier) : (-1 * dirModifier);
```

Otherwise, sort will be by string value ("2" is bigger than "10").

In general, to sort by numeric value:

```
array.sort((a,b)=>parseFloat(a)<parseFloat(b)?-1:1)
```